# Get Average of column using group by

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the average of property from table based on its group,

```
from avgtbl1 in table1
group avgtbl1 by new
{
    avgtbl1 .Prop1,
    avgtbl1 .Prop2,
    avgtbl1 .Prop3,
    avgtbl1 .Prop4
} into tempavgtbl1 
select new
{
    Prop1= tempavgtbl1 .Key.Prop1,
    Prop2= tempavgtbl1 .Key.Prop2,
    Prop3= tempavgtbl1 .Key.Prop3,
    Prop4= tempavgtbl1 .Key.Prop4,
    prop5= tempavgtbl1 .Average(a =>  a.Prop4)
};
```

After executing the query it's gives same value of prop4 rather than a average of group for prop4 which is based on prop1,prop2,prop3. I am not getting where i went wrong.

```
 |Prop1 | prop2 |prop3| prop4|
 |1     | abc   |123  |    20|
 |1     | abc   |123  |    24|
 |2     | abc   |123  |    20|
 |2     | abc   |123  |    24|
 |3     | pqr   |  123|    27|
 |3     | pqr   |  123|    29|



 Expected Result

 |Prop1 | prop2 |prop3| prop4|prop5|
 |1     | abc   |123  |    20| 22  |
 |1     | abc   |123  |    24| 22  |
 |2     | abc   |123  |    21| 22.5|
 |2     | abc   |123  |    24| 22.5|
 |3     | pqr   |  123|    27| 28  |
 |3     | pqr   |  123|    29| 28  |
```

Current result:

```
 |Prop1 | prop2 |prop3| prop4|prop5|
 |1     | abc   |123  |    20|   20|
 |1     | abc   |123  |    24|   24|
 |2     | abc   |123  |    21|   21|
 |2     | abc   |123  |    24|   24|
 |3     | pqr   |  123|    27|   27|
 |3     | pqr   |  123|    29|   29|
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected result of the query? What actual result you are getting with the sample data?

Comment: sure editing question with sample data

Comment: You should group by only Prop1, Prop2, and Prop3. You have different values in Prop4 which makes the rows unique and group by will not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are grouping on `Prop4`.  To do what you want you'll have to calculate the average then join back to the original table to get the un-averaged values.  Also you can just group `Prop4` by the other columns so that you don't have to specify the column in the `Average`.

```
from a1 in table1
group a1.Prop4 by new
{
    a1.Prop1,
    a1.Prop2,
    a1.Prop3
} into grp
join a2 in table1 
on grp.Key equals new {a2.Prop1, a2.Prop2, a2.Prop3};    
select new
{
    a2.Prop1, // or grp.Key.Prop1,
    a2.Prop2, // or grp.Key.Prop2,
    a2.Prop3, // or grp.Key.Prop3,
    a2.Prop4,
    Prop5 = grp.Average()
}
```

Alternatively this can also be done with a subquery.

```
from a1 in table1 
select new
{
    a1.Prop1, 
    a1.Prop2, 
    a1.Prop3, 
    a1.Prop4,
    Prop5 = (from a2 in table1
             where a2.Prop1 = a1.Prop1
                   && a2.Prop2 = a1.Prop2
                   && a2.Prop3 = a1.Prop3
             select a2.Prop4).Average()
}
```